# Can struct-like enums be used as types?

Tags: enums, rust

Consider the following (illegal) example:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar { i: i32 },
    Baz,
}

struct MyStruct {
    field: Foo::Bar,
}
```

`Foo::Bar` is a [struct-like variant](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0418-struct-variants.md). I've found them to be quite useful. However, I have an instance where I need to store an instance of the struct inside another struct, like the above example of `MyStruct`. Changing `MyStruct::field` to be a `Foo` would be invalid, as it doesn't make sense for the field to be a `Foo::Baz`. It's just meant to be an instance of `Foo::Bar`.

`rustc` tells me the above code is invalid:

```
error: found value name used as a type: DefVariant(DefId { krate: 0u32, node: 4u32 }, DefId { krate: 0u32, node: 5u32 }, true)
```

Am I just doing something wrong, or is this not possible? If it's not possible, are there any plans on doing it?

I know I could work around it like this, but I consider it an inferior option and it's one I'd like to avoid if possible:

```
struct Bar {
    i: i32,
}

enum Foo {
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz,
}

struct MyStruct {
    field: Bar,
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this first situation,

```
enum Foo {
    Bar { i: i32 },
    Baz,
}
```

as the compiler tells you `Bar` is not a type but a value, and cannot be used as a type (`error: found value name used as a type`).

You second construction is what is generally used, for example in the standard library with [`std::net::IpAddr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) and [`std::net::SocketAddr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html).

Answer (score 7):

No, an enum variant is not a type in its own right and cannot be used as a type.