# Defining a method for a struct only when a field is a certain enum variant?

Tags: enums, rust, type-safety, type-parameter, downcast

I have the following struct:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Entry {
    pub index: usize,
    pub name: String,
    pub filename_offset: u64,
    pub entry_type: EntryType,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum EntryType {
    File {
        file_offset: u64,
        length: usize,
    },

    Directory {
        parent_index: usize,
        next_index: usize,
    },
}
```

`Entry` is an entry in a GameCube ROM file system table which describes a file or directory. I defined various methods for `Entry` such as `Entry::read_filename` and `Entry::write_to_disk`. However, I have some methods that don't make sense to be available to both regular files and directories. For example, `Entry::iter_contents` iterates over all of a directory's child entries.

I want to be able to define certain methods such as `Entry::iter_contents` only for entries where `entry_type` is a certain variant.

I tried turning `EntryType` into a trait and made a `DirectoryEntryInfo` and `FileEntryInfo` struct, which both implemented `EntryType`.

Sadly, there were some problems with this approach. I have a `Vec<Entry>` elsewhere and with this change it would become `Vec<Entry<EntryType>>`. Using a trait like this, I have no way to downcast `Entry<EntryList>` to `Entry<DirectoryEntryInfo>`. I also tried doing something with `Any`, as that is the only way I am aware of to downcast in Rust, but I was only able to cast `entry_type`, not the entire `Entry` itself.

Ultimately, I'd like to end up with something similar to this:

```
impl<T: EntryType> Entry<T> {
    pub fn as_dir(&self) -> Option<Entry<DirectoryEntryInfo>> { ... }
    pub fn as_file(&self) -> Option<Entry<FileEntryInfo>> { ... }
    ...
}

impl Entry<DirectoryEntryInfo> {
    ...
}

impl Entry<FileEntryInfo> {
    ...
}
```

This way, I could access all of the entries fields without knowing whether or not it's a directory or file, as well as be able to cast it to a type that would provide me with all of the `Entry` fields in addition to methods based on the type parameter like `Entry::iter_contents`.

Is there a good way to do this without something like [RFC 1450](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450)?

I'm aware that enum variants are not their own types and cannot be used as type parameters. I am just looking for an alternate way to conditionally define a method for a struct and still be able to have a way to store any variant of this struct in something like a `Vec`. [This article](https://rreverser.com/conditional-enum-variants-in-rust/) is extremely close to what I am trying to do. However, using the example from it, there is no way to store a `MyEnum<Bool>` without knowing whether that `Bool` is `True` or `False` at compile time. Being able to downcast something like `MyEnum<Box<Bool>>` to `MyEnum<False>` would fix this, but I'm not aware of anything like that in Rust.

Comment: No; enum variants are not their own types thus they cannot participate in the type system. See also [Can struct-like enums be used as types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29935878/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Is there another way without enums to accomplish what I've tried to do? I mentioned making `EntryType` a trait, and trying to use two structs which both implement `EntryType`. However I ran into issues there because I couldn't downcast `Entry<EntryType>` into `EntryType<DirectoryEntryInfo>` or `EntryType<FileEntryInfo>`. I'm not set on using enums, I'm open to anything that'll get the kind of behavior I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm aware enum variants are not their own type, I should have been more specific. I'm just looking for a way to do something similar as a workaround, regardless of whether it involves enums or not.

Comment: I wrote an answer based on `enum`, but there's a downcasting solution too, using `Box`, if you make `EntryType` require `Any`. [I wrote this too, which may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47642317/3650362)

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try out both of those, but I have a feeling the `enum` based one will be best for my use case.

Comment: @trentcl it's probably worth putting that into your answer (or even a second answer if you feel they are different enough). Comments are ephemeral and useful solutions shouldn't be lost.

Comment: @Shepmaster well, I gave it a shot, but [the solution I came up with using `Box`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b5db46d5f8815d9d4bbcdde5a624905c&version=stable) is such an abomination that I think, on the whole, I'd rather not! (Anyone reading this may feel free to use it in their own answer, or as an example of what *not* to do.)

Comment: @trentcl sometimes an answer showing a poor solution and explaining why it is poor is useful too ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do *quite* that, because (as mentioned in the question comments) [enum variants are not types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935878/can-struct-like-enums-be-used-as-types) and information about the variant isn't available to the type system.

One possible approach is to "hoist" the `enum` to the outer layer and have each variant contain a `struct` that wraps the shared data:

```
struct EntryInfo {
    index: usize,
    name: String,
    filename_offset: u64,
}

pub struct FileEntry {
    info: EntryInfo,
    file_offset: u64,
    length: usize,
}

pub struct DirEntry {
    info: EntryInfo,
    parent_index: usize,
    next_index: usize,
}

pub enum Entry {
    File(FileEntry),
    Dir(DirEntry),
}
```

Then you can easily define `as_file` and `as_dir` along the following lines:

```
impl Entry {
    pub fn as_dir(&self) -> Option<&DirEntry> {
        match *self {
            Entry::Dir(ref d) => Some(d),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    pub fn as_file(&self) -> Option<&FileEntry> {
        match *self {
            Entry::File(ref f) => Some(f),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

It's not ideal, because any code you would have written on `Entry` before now needs to defer to `EntryInfo` in the appropriate variant. One thing that can make things easier is writing a helper method to find the wrapped `EntryInfo`:

```
fn as_info(&self) -> &EntryInfo {
    match *self {
        Entry::Dir(ref d) => &d.info,
        Entry::File(ref f) => &f.info,
    }
}
```

Then you can use `self.as_info()` instead of `self.info` in the implementation of `Entry`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great and is exactly what I needed!