# How do I use serde to deserialize into a specific enum variant?

Tags: enums, rust, variant, serde

I have an enum defined as:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Bar { x: i32, y: i32 },
    ... // many more variants
}
```

Given a JSON string `{"x": 5, "y": 7}` how would I deserialize explicitly to `Foo::Bar {x: 5, y: 7}`?

Ideally I would be able to call into the deserializer for a particular variant, i.e. `Foo::Bar` in my example, rather than resort to something like `#[serde(untagged)]` which is a poor fit when you know in advance which variant to use.

I could define `Bar` as a type in its own right but since it's only ever used in the context of `Foo`, it doesn't seem like the most elegant and/or succinct solution.

Comment: If you know for sure you are going to have a `Foo::Bar`, why use the enum in the first place rather than making `Bar` a type on its own?

Comment: The enum represents an HTTP request message or _route_. I know from the path which message to create. In the example, `Bar` represents a particular route and the struct might then be deserialized from the HTTP request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `Bar` as a type in its own right:

```
#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
enum Foo {
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz,
}

#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
struct Bar {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() -> serde_json::Result<()> {
    let bar = serde_json::from_str::<Bar>(r#"{"x": 5, "y": 7}"#)?;
    println!("{:?}", bar);
    Ok(())
}
```

- [Unwrap inner type when enum variant is known](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34953711/155423)
- [Defining a method for a struct only when a field is a certain enum variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48120780/155423)
- [Can traits be used on enum types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567350/155423)
- [How do I pass an enum variant to match on as a function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57171185/155423)