# Can traits be used on enum types?

Tags: enums, rust, traits

I read through the [trait documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html) and found a neat definition for using traits on structs. Is it possible to use traits on `enum` types? I have seen answers that say no, but they are 3 years old and don't quite do what I'm trying to do.

I tried to do this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum SceneType {
    Cutscene,
    Game,
    Menu,
    Pause,
    Credits,
    Exit,
}

//We want to guarantee every SceneType can be played statically
trait Playable {
    fn play();
}

impl Playable for SceneType::Cutscene {
    fn play() {}
}
```

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found variant `SceneType::Cutscene`
  --> src/main.rs:16:19
   |
16 | impl Playable for SceneType::Cutscene {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                   |
   |                   not a type
   |                   help: you can try using the variant's enum: `SceneType`
```

I don't understand this error because the enum it references is in the same file. If I really can't use traits on enum variants, is there any way I can guarantee any enum trait must implement certain methods?

Answer (score 37):

> Can traits be used on enum types?

**Yes**. In fact, you already have multiple traits defined for your enum; the traits [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html), [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) and [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html):

> ```
> #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
> pub enum SceneType
> ```

The problem is that you aren't attempting to implement `Playable` for your enum, you are trying to implement it for one of the enum's *variants*. Enum variants *are not types*.

As the error message tells you:

> ```
> help: you can try using the variant's enum: `SceneType`
> ```

```
impl Playable for SceneType {
    fn play() {}
}
```

See also:

- [Can struct-like enums be used as types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29935878/155423)
- [Is there a way to use existing structs as enum variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49705007/155423)

Comment: But if  I want implement Playable for all enum variants ( Cutscene.play(), Game.play(), etc), what should I do? Add `match` expression to SceneType.play() method?

Comment: @rusnasonov yes.

Comment: Isn't that weird of the language since it allows enums of different data types. So not allowing trait on enum is a bit counter-intuitive. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement a trait for `Playable` (i.e. for *all* enum variants) then the answer is quite simply: Yes you can. And Shepmaster's answer details how to do that.

However, if you really only want one enum variant to be `Playable` and not the others, then Rust doesn't directly support that, but there's an idiom I've seen used to emulate it. Instead of

```
enum MyEnum {
  A(i32, i32),
  B(String),
}
```

you explicitly implement each enum variant as a separate struct, so

```
enum MyEnum {
  A(A),
  B(B),
}

struct A {
  x: i32,
  y: i32,
}

struct B {
  name: String,
}
```

And then you can `impl Playable for A` without `impl Playable for B`. Whenever you want to call it, pattern match the `MyEnum` and, if you get an `A`, you can call `play` in your example on the result of the pattern match.

I don't recommend using this pattern for *every* enum you write, as it does make the code a decent bit more verbose and requires some boilerplate constructor methods to make it palatable. But for complicated enums with a lot of options, this sort of pattern can make the code easier to reason about, especially if you have a lot of traits or functions that only really apply to a couple of the enum possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Truly apologize; this answer isn't about

> every SceneType can be played statically

---

**Old answer**

Try generics:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum SceneType <Cutscene>
where
    Cutscene: Playable
{
    Cutscene(Cutscene),
    Game,
    Menu,
    Pause,
    Credits,
    Exit,
}

//We want to guarantee every SceneType can be played statically
// Notice: add `pub` as enum
pub trait Playable {
    fn play();
}

// create struct for inner of SceneType::Cutscene 
struct Cutscene {
    // ...
}

// impl to specific Cutscene
impl Playable for Cutscene {
    fn play() {}
}
```

Test it:

```
fn main () {
    let cutscene = Cutscene{};
    let scenetype = SceneType::Cutscene(cutscene);
}
```

A downside I realized is that the generics are static. When there are more than one generics for an enum, all generics must be specified.

```
enum E <A, B>
where
    A: SomeTrait1,
    B: SomeTrait2,
{
    Enum1(A),
    Enum2(B),
}

trait SomeTrait1 {}
trait SomeTrait2 {}

struct S1 {}
impl SomeTrait1 for S1{}

struct S2 {}
impl SomeTrait2 for S2{}

struct X1 {}
impl SomeTrait1 for X1{}

fn main () {
    // specify the generics
    E::<S1, S2>::Enum1(S1{});
    E::<X1, S2>::Enum1(X1{});

    //error[E0282]: type annotations needed
    //  --> src/main.rs:26:5
    //   |
    //33 |     E::Enum1(S1{});
    //   |     ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `B` declared on the enum `E`
    // E::Enum1(S1{});
    // E::Enum1(X1{});
}
```