# How to make a struct containing an enum generic over the enum variant?

Tags: types, rust

Please have a look at the code:

```
struct Human {
  name: String,
  profession: Profession,
}

enum Profession {
  Doctor,
  Teacher
}

struct Family {
  family_doctor: // How to express type that will mean Human (because name matters) of profession Doctor?
}
```

Is it possible to do that, by making `Human` generic somehow, and pass variant `Doctor` as a type parameter for `profession` field? If not, then what is the closest workaround for such relationships you would suggest?

*Please note* that this question may seem as a duplicate of an older one. But firstly, Rust keeps evolving, secondly, I am asking for a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to make `Profession` a trait rather than an `enum`, and make each `Profession` a unit struct:

```
struct Human<P: ?Sized + Profession> {
  name: String,
  profession: P,
}

struct Doctor;
struct Teacher;

trait Profession {}

impl Profession for Doctor {}
impl Profession for Teacher {}

struct Family {
  family_doctor: Human<Doctor>,
}
```

Most functions that accept Humans can be expressed using generics or `impl Profession`:

```
fn into_name<P: Profession>(any_human: Human<P>) -> String {
    any_human.name
}
```

Another way of writing functions that accept different kinds of Human is to use dynamic dispatch. If you do it this way, any access to a `Human` has to be done through a pointer, like `Box<Human<dyn Profession>>` or `&Human<dyn Profession>` (note [this works because of `P: ?Sized`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/3650362) in the definition of `Human`):

```
fn into_name_dyn(any_human: Box<Human<dyn Profession>>) -> String {
    any_human.name
}
```

Yet another possibility is to implement `Profession` for `Box<dyn Profession>` and use that as the type parameter. This puts the pointer inside `Human` so only the `Profession` is behind it:

```
impl<P: ?Sized + Profession> Profession for Box<P> {}

fn into_name_box(any_human: Human<Box<dyn Profession>>) -> String {
    any_human.name
}
```

If you still want the `enum`, here's one suggestion: put the structs inside same-named variants. This way when you add behavior to the `Profession` trait, you can implement `Profession` for `SomeProfession` by deferring to the inner type's implementation. The `enum_derive` crate can make this process easier.

```
enum SomeProfession {
    Doctor(Doctor),
    Teacher(Teacher),
}

impl Profession for SomeProfession {}

fn into_name_enum(any_human: Human<SomeProfession>) -> String {
    any_human.name
}
```

## See also

- [How can I implement a trait in scope for an enum of existing types for which the trait is implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51661392/3650362)
- [Is there a way to use existing structs as enum variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49705007/3650362)

Comment: This solution imply that an human can't change of profession.

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing answer! The last approach totally made sense to me, also looked nice. That said, in order to solve my original problem which is really duplication of fields, I am more inclined to use the composition approach, which is putting the duplicated fields into a struct. Your answer showed to me what are the options, and let me choose.

Comment: What does `Human` refer to in the final example?