Elegant way to map error message to error enum in rust?
I'm new to Rust and I'm writing my version of xxd.
There's the cli module in cli.rs:
use std::env;

pub enum ArgumentError {
    TooManyArguments
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum InputType {
    FILE(String),
    INPUT
}


pub fn get_args() -> Result<InputType, ArgumentError>{
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    
    match args.len() {
        0 => Ok(InputType::INPUT),
        1 => Ok(InputType::FILE(args[0])),
        _ => Err(ArgumentError::TooManyArguments)
    }
}

In main.rs I have the following code:
enum MyXXDError {
    TooManyArguments(&'static str),
}


fn get_file() -> Result<cli::InputType, MyXXDError> {
    let args = cli::get_args();

    match args {
        Ok(input_type) => Ok(input_type),
        Err(error) => Err(
            match error {
                ArgumentError::TooManyArguments => MyXXDError::TooManyArguments("Too many arguments inserted.")
            }
        )
    }
}

My question is, how can I print the error message of the MyXXDError in a way that would work on every enum value I could add in the future (Assuming every future enum element would contain a &str)?

Have your enum implement a trait that exposes the error-message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567350/can-traits-be-used-on-enum-types

You could just #[derive(Debug)] (and if you want implement Display in terms of it)

Can you please clarify your title? It seems to be asking a completely different question from the body of your question.

Consider using the thiserror crate and deriving thiserror::Error, which will implement Error and Display for you.

I think you should implement Display/Debug for ArgumentError, and use the try operator in the get_file function (I assume you will add more logic below that match)
Also: pls use CamelCase for enum variants ;)

...if you added the code you're describing this would be an actual answer...
