# How do I pass an enum variant to match on as a function parameter?

Tags: enums, rust, matching

I would like to pass in the parameters what arm of the enum I need to match, something like this:

```rust
enum D {
    A(i64),
    B(u64),
    C(u64, u64),
}
```

```rust
let a = D.A(10);
println!(a.is_of(D.A)); // true
println!(a.is_of(D.B)); // false
```

I know I can use matching rules for this, but I'd like this `is_of` method to take as an input of the enum options for my purposes.

Comment: [`matches!(a, D::A(_))`](https://crates.io/crates/matches)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot.

- It is not possible to pass types as function parameters.
- Enum variants are not types to start with.

If you are OK using a macro instead of a function, see

- [How do I assert an enum is a specific variant if I don't care about its fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123901/155423)
- The [matches crate](https://crates.io/crates/matches)

See also:

- [Compare enums only by variant, not value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32554285/155423)
- [Can traits be used on enum types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567350/155423)
- [Can struct-like enums be used as types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29935878/155423)
- [Is there a way to use existing structs as enum variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49705007/155423)

Comment: Man.. I still don't know why enums cannot be passed as parameters in Rust. It's really counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

The discriminant of an enum variant can be passed for compairson

```rust
use std::mem::{discriminant,Discriminant};

enum MyEnum {
  A,
  B,
}

fn is_enum_variant(value: &MyEnum, d: Discriminant<MyEnum>) -> bool {
  discriminant(value) == d
}

fn main() {
  println!("Is variant: {}", is_enum_variant(&MyEnum::A, discriminant(&MyEnum::A)));
  println!("Is variant: {}", is_enum_variant(&MyEnum::A, discriminant(&MyEnum::B)));
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=48100532d7bc0a6eca77ded73bbf422f)